# Parallelize loop with "non-mapable" function in Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, joblib

I solve numerically integral equation on the time interval from `0` to `Tmax` with predefined step `dT`. I do it in the for loop:

```
list_of_values = []

for i in range(dT,Tmax+dT,dT):
   func_at_t= my_fancy_solver(func_at_t)
   list_of_values.append(func_at_t)
```

The function `my_fancy_solver` has one argument and inside it looks as follows:

```
def my_fancy_solver(func_at_prev_t):
    while True:
        # iterate in while loop until convergence will achieved
        # compute approx_error and func_at_new_t_approx
        if approx_error < 10**(-10):
            func_at_new_t = func_at_new_t_approx
            break
    return func_at_new_t
```

which means that this solver deals with function value at the previous moment of time `func_at_prev_t` and approximate a unknown value of function at next moment of time `func_at_new_t`. It happens in while-loop until desired accuracy will achieved, which is controlled by `approx_error` variable. It means that in line

```
func_at_t= my_fancy_solver(func_at_t)
```

(as I assume) I find function value at a given moment of time and then use it to find the next value.

I would like to understand how can I parallelize this computation. My confusion is that the function `my_fancy_solver` is not mappable, so I cannot represent it as `map(my_fancy_solver, t)` where `t` is a given time value. So, I do not understandt how can I perform parallelization with help of `multiprocessing` or `joblib`. Can anyone give some advice?

Comment: How do you use `i`? Is time an argument in `my_fancy_solver`? And isn't `i`, the given time value, so is same as `t`?

Comment: @Parfait , `i` does not appear explicitly in `my_fancy_solver`. My solver perform solution from time `T0` to time `T0+dT`, so I doe not use `i` explicitly, only as counter of number of iterations. Yes, `i` is the same as `t`.

Comment: Please show sample definition of `my_fancy_solver`. I need to see arguments. Why is `function_at_t` both assigned and an argument?

Comment: @Parfait , I have tried to provide more details

Comment: Is `func_at_t` initially assigned somewhere? As written, your loop should err out: `local variable 'func_at_t' referenced before assignment`. You have to be passing it `t` somewhere in your method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your following answer comment, you may have a reduce-able function:

> I use previosly found `function_at_t` in next iteration

Hence, consider [**`functools.reduce`**](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) which is one of the higher-order functions (map/reduce/filter), or [**`itertools.accumulate`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) to keep intermediate values in a list.

Because `reduce` and `accumulate` expect a method of two arguments, below uses a layered method to accumulate results and below assumes your function, `my_fancy_solver`, receives time as only required argument.

```py
from functools import reduce
from itertools import accumulate

...

def my_fancy_process(accum_value, time): 
    return accum_value + my_fancy_solver(time)

final_single_value = reduce(
    my_fancy_process, iterable=range(dT, Tmax+dT, dT), initializer=0)
)

list_of_values = accumulate(
    range(dT, Tmax+dT, dT), func=my_fancy_process, initial=0
)
```

Search online for examples of how to parallelize `reduce` and `accumulate` calls.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you need a mapper at all to parallelize this. Of course, if needed, you can map it to a list of tuples corresponding to arguments, but mapping itself doesn't seem to help here, correct me if I'm understanding you wrong.

For example, this loop can be parallelized like:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
    
results = Parallel(n_jobs=2)(
    delayed(my_fancy_solver)(initial_condition, function_at_t)
    for i in range(dT, Tmax+dT, dT)
)

print(results)
```

Of course, you can do the same with a regular loop

Comment: Will check it. I assumed that this will work only for mappable function

Comment: Actually anything callable can be used as a map argument in Python (even `str`) so I believe there are no non-mappable functions at all

Comment: But to be honest I do not understand how to update `function_at_t` variable. As you can see, I use previosly found `function_at_t` in next iteration. If I undestand correctly, the proposed by you solution will simply gives list of values, i.e. `result` will contain identically elements because in this loop I do not see update of variable `function_at_t` explicitly. I wll check documentaion for joblib